# How to change pop-up location of google charts tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I currently have html enabled tooltips that also display "sub graphs". However, it would be nice if it was possible to have all tooltips pop up in a fixed location or have an offset that adjusted their relative poition.

[image]

This is an example of the kind of tooltip that I have (blank data). I'd like to move it to the right. Any suggestions would be appreciated, including any javascript trickery.

Comment: Does [this](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-customize-tooltip-text-using-html-tags-in-google-charts/) help?

Comment: Nah that just modifies the html within the tooltip. Has nothing to do with where it actually pops up.

Comment: We actually just implemented the ability to slightly control the direction of the tooltips. It will be in the next release (v40), but I can't tell you when that will be out, because Google doesn't preannounce. I'd keep my eyes on the google-visualization-api mailing list for the release. It should be announced in a couple of days/weeks. Also, @asgallant's answers tend to be solid. Check it out below...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tooltip position is set inline, so you need to listen for DOM insertion of the tooltip and change the position manually.  Mutation events are deprecated, so use a `MutationObserver` if it is available (Chrome, Firefox, IE11) and a `DOMNodeInserted` event handler if not (IE 9, 10).  This will not work in IE8.

```
google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(myChart, 'ready', function () {
    var container = document.querySelector('#myChartDiv > div:last-child');
    function setPosition () {
        var tooltip = container.querySelector('div.google-visualization-tooltip');
        tooltip.style.top = 0;
        tooltip.style.left = 0;
    }
    if (typeof MutationObserver === 'function') {
        var observer = new MutationObserver(function (m) {
            for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
                if (m[i].addedNodes.length) {
                    setPosition();
                    break; // once we find the added node, we shouldn't need to look any further
                }
            }
        });
        observer.observe(container, {
            childList: true
        });
    }
    else if (document.addEventListener) {
        container.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', setPosition);
    }
    else {
        container.attachEvent('onDOMNodeInserted', setPosition);
    }
});
```

The `MutationObserver` should be fine, but the events may need some work; I didn't test them.

Comment: @asgallant Great answer, although I had some trouble implementing it as per the answer I've added below.

Comment: Great it works well now. Thanks as well @AlanBuchanan for your answer too.

Comment: I cannot get this working. The MutationObserver callback is never executed.
I guess it should be executed when the user hovers the graph that makes the tooltip appear.

Answer (score 17):

whilst the answer is very good it is a little outdated now.  Google has implemented CSS control so there is greater flexibility without the need to hack the JavaScript.

```
.google-visualization-tooltip {  position:relative !important; top:0 !important;right:0 !important; z-index:+1;}
```

will provide a tooltip fixed at the bottom of the chart, live example: http://www.taxformcalculator.com/federal-budget/130000.html

alternatively you could just tweak the left margin...

```
.google-visualization-tooltip {  margin-left: 150px !important; z-index:+1;}
```

Note that pulling the container forward with z-index reduces (but does not stop entirely) visibility flicker as the mouse moves.  The degree of flicker will vary on chart size, call etc. Personally, I prefer to fix the tool tip and make it part of the design as per the first example.  Hope this helps those who are deterred by the JS hack (which is good but really no longer necessary).

Answer (score 3):

I had more or less the same question as Redshift, having been trying to move the tooltip relative to the node being hovered over. Using asgallant's fantastic answer I've implemented his code as below.

I haven't been able to test whether this works with the `MutationObserver` because during my testing in Firefox, Chrome and IE11 it always fails that test and uses addEventListener. The docs suggest it should work though.

I had to introduce a timeout to actually manipulate the styles as otherwise the left and top position of the element was always reported as 0. My assumption is that the event fired upon addition of the node but the DOM wasn't quite ready. This is just a guess though and I'm not 100% happy with implementing it in this way.

```
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));
  google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var container = document.querySelector('#line_chart > div:last-child');
    function setPosition(e) {
      if (e && e.target) {
        var tooltip = $(e.target);
          setTimeout(function () {
            var left = parseFloat(tooltip.css('left')) - 49;
            var top = parseFloat(tooltip.css('top')) - 40;
            tooltip.css('left', left + 'px');
            tooltip.css('top', top + 'px');
            $(".google-visualization-tooltip").fadeIn(200);
          }, 1);
      }
      else {
        var tooltip = container.querySelector('.google-visualization-tooltip');
        var left = parseFloat(tooltip.style.left) - 49;
        var top = parseFloat(tooltip.style.top) - 40;
        tooltip.style.left = left + 'px';
        tooltip.style.top = top + 'px';
        $(".google-visualization-tooltip").fadeIn(200);
      }
    }
    if (typeof MutationObserver === 'function') {
      var observer = new MutationObserver(function (m) {
        if (m.length && m[0].addedNodes.length) {
          setPosition(m);
        }
      });
      observer.observe(container, {
        childList: true
      });
    }
    else if (document.addEventListener) {
      container.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', setPosition);
    }
    else {
      container.attachEvent('onDOMNodeInserted', setPosition);
    }
  });
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

EDIT: Updated to get the `MutationObserver` working following asgallant's comment.

Comment: That's my goof - it should be `typeof MutationObserver === 'function'` .

Comment: @asgallant Thanks, that's working now and I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @asgallant, I have implemented the combination of both of your work and now have a partially working solution. My problem is that the tooltip does now shift - but only when the mouse leaves a point and then goes to another. As I have points very close to each other, what often happens is that whilst one tooltip is showing up, and I move to another point (without it disappearing) the tooltip position resets to the default. Do either of you have any suggestions as to what might be going on? Thanks for both of your efforts anyway.

Comment: @RedShift Are you able to put a breakpoint in the setPosition() function using Firebug (or just an alert box), to check whether the event is being fired as the cursor moves from one point to another. It may be that the code moves the tooltip element in this circumstance, rather than removing it and re-adding it to the DOM.

Comment: I'll check it out when I'm next at work (2days) and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: The `MutationObserver` object works differently than events (see [MDN docs on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)); there may be multiple mutations observed, so you would have to parse the entire array instead of checking the first element.  I'll update my answer with code to do this.

Comment: In the new code in my answer, I break after locating the newly inserted element, but I'm not certain that this will work correctly with your version, as you are passing in the event object, which could end up pointing to a removed node if there are multiple tooltips spawned between observations.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for html tooltips in a timeline chart? Would this be possible there? @AGB