# r googleVis: How to control html tooltips (positioning, border and background)

Tags: r, googlevis

I have figured out how to create custom html tooltips by [using roles via googleVis](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/Using_Roles_via_googleVis.html). I can easily modify the content using html but I cannot understand how I can control the tooltip box itself.

My problem was generated because some of the custom tooltips I created are falling outside my chart area and I tried (unsuccessfully) to find a way to control the tooltip position. Idealy I would like to make them behave in the exact same way default tooltips behave in googleVis (always stay withinin the chart area).

When I later implemented the same concept into a line chart I found that I have another problem as well. The tooltip is falling on the line so I cannot see what is the exact point that refers to the tooltip.

Would it be possible for example to keep the callout style of default googleVis tooltip and change the content with HTML?

Additionally, do you know if there is any way to control more tooltip properties like border and background color?

Comment: I have found this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795432/how-to-change-pop-up-location-of-google-charts-tooltip) which seems to be addressing the issue outside r.

Answer (score 0):

i was also looking for the same

1) when laying out your data, make sure it has columns alternating between, say, data and tooltips, data and tooltips,... that way it is possible to customize tooltips for multiple columns (it does not work if you just append - à la cbind - a set of tooltips columns to your data frame).

Additionally try this http://rcharts.io/viewer/?6644957#.VHcpEkvrdbg