# Change position of tooltip in Google Chart

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I have a google chart that I'm using where I have set the type of tooltip to be html in my options, like this:

```
tooltip: { isHtml: true }
```

Customizing the tooltip to look how I want has been the easy part, but getting the tooltip in the right position has surprisingly difficult.  After a lot of searching, I found this answer on [tooltip positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795432/how-to-change-pop-up-location-of-google-charts-tooltip), but cannot seem to get it working.

My javascript (aside from options) for creating the chart and dealing with tooltip positioning is as follows:

```
    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
        var container = document.querySelector('#chart_div > div:last-child');
        function setPosition () {
            var tooltip = container.querySelector('div.google-visualization-tooltip');
            tooltip.style.top = 0;
            tooltip.style.left = '-47px';
        }
        if (typeof MutationObserver === 'function') {
            var observer = new MutationObserver(function (m) {
                for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
                    console.log("mutation: " + m[i].type);
                    if (m[i].addedNodes.length) {
                        setPosition();
                        break; // once we find the added node, we shouldn't need to look any further
                    }
                }
            });
            observer.observe(container, {
                childList: true
            });
        } else if (document.addEventListener) {
            container.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', setPosition);
        } else {
            container.attachEvent('onDOMNodeInserted', setPosition);
        }
    });
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
```

I'm using Google Chrome for testing right now, and if I put a debugger in the `typeof MutationObserver` snippet, I am getting in there and setting the observer, but it seems as though it never gets observed, as I am not even getting the console messages.

Any help would be very appreciated.  My html element with the ID `chart_div` exists (and the chart is rendered there), so I am not sure what I am missing.